# Can Present Perfect with a stative verb be used to describe a finished action?

Tags: present-perfect, stative-verbs

I learned that if a stative verb was used in present perfect form, this would indicate an **unfinished/continuing action**, i.e "I have liked pasta since I was a baby."
However, there are also cases such as "I have been to this place before", where I use the stative verb ("be") in present perfect form but still describe a **finished action**.

Is the verb considered dynamic in this case?
Thank you!

Comment: In *I have been*, *been* is acting as the past participle of to *go* (the past simple equivalent of *have you ever been* is *did you ever go*). In this use *been* is not stative, so there is no breach of the rule you were taught. The same is true IMHO of @DavidSiegel's examples below - in *I have liked pasta, on rare occasions*, the meaning can't be stative, because there is no continuity - it is like *I liked that steak a whole lot*...

Comment: *I have liked pasta since I was a baby, but now I can't stand it* is not grammatical for me. *I have liked the pasta in some places we've been, but tonight I don't fancy it* is fine, but then we're back to the non-stative use.

Answer (score 2):

As with so many "rules" about English grammar and usage, this one isn't in fact a rule.

> I have liked pasta since I was a baby.

implies that the speaker still likes it. However, the sentence:

> I have liked pasta since I was a baby, but now I can't stand it.

denies that implication, without in any way changign the grammer of the first clause. Furthermore a sentence such as

> I have liked pasta -- on rare occasions.

certainly carries no implication of continuing liking, but the grammar of "have liked" is unchanged. That this form shows a continuing action is the defaiult state of things, but only until context indicates otherwise.

The sentence:

> I have been to this place before.

does not in any way imply that this is a continuing action. I am not sure if the verb would be labelled "stative" in this usage, and I am less concerned by such labels than by the overall meaning of the expression.

Comment: Okay, I understand. What about the second sentence? Would it also be an example of an exception to the "rule"?

Comment: @Kohei Sanno I added that to the answer.

Comment: ***I've / I have** always liked pasta until today* is fine. *I've always liked pasta until yesterday* is at least "suspect", and *I've always liked pasta until two years ago* is decidedly unlikely - it would normally be Simple Past *I always liked pasta until [some point in the past when I **stopped** liking it]*.

Comment: "I have liked pasta since I was a baby, but now I can't stand it." is it grammatical ?I think so because it has very recently changed and present perfect can be used to express that recent change